# Using log (or other object from index.js) in nodejs modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, module

I recently had the idea of using `winston` logging in nodejs. I started configuring it and it started to grow. I use it in my index.js file, but it started to get big and then I separated that file in modules. I want to log things that happens in the modules also, but for that I'd need to either require and reconfigure the winston log every time, or inject the winston logger from index.js into the modules. I think the last way is better, but is there a better way? My idea is: suppose loggin is my configured logging object, here's what I would do in each myModule.js:

```
var logging;
module.exports.injectLog(loggingObject) {
    this.logging = loggingObject;
}
module.exports.someFunctionThatNeedsToBeLogged() {
//do something
logging("doing some log");
}
```

Then in index.js I would require the module like this:

```
var myModule = require('./myModule.js').injectLog(loggingObject);
```

is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve what you're asking, a couple which I believe are cleaner than what you're describing.

You could supply a dependency object to each module that requires logging when requiring it. You could even move that to a config module to keep `index.js` clean

```
// index.js
var winston = require('winston');
winston.configure({
  // config etc etc
});

var deps = {
  logger: winston
 }

var someOtherModule = require("./some-other-module")(deps);


// someOtherModule
module.exports = function(deps){
  var logger = deps.logger;
  // return your module
}
```

That way you can easily add additional dependencies when they arrive.

I think my preferred way would be to write a light wrapper around the logger and require it wherever required.

```
// logger.js
const winston = require('winston');
winston.configure({
  // config etc etc
});
module.exports = winston;


// index.js
var logger = require("./logger");

// some-other-module
var logger = require("./logger");
```

Comment: Wouldn't I be loading the logger 2 times? One when I require a module that uses the logger, and another when I require the logger in index.js?

Comment: It should be cached by node the first time it's loaded. This should be easy to verify by adding a `console.log('testing');` after `winston.configure...`